# How to make a 3TB virtual drive for virtualbox?

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, vhd

I need to make a large virtual drive for virtual box at 3TB, however, the max size in virtual box appears to be 2TB. How can i make a 3TB virtual disk/drive? thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not use the GUI to accomplish this, but you can with the command line like:

```
 vboxmanage createhd --filename 3TB.vdi --size 3000000 --format VDI --variant Standard
```

[reference](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=46991)

Comment: Great! does this also work for fixed size disks at this size?

Comment: Based on [this](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-createvdi) I assume `--variant Fixed` would work for a 3T drive, but I have not tested it.